# Serialised Array not working

Tags: php, arrays, csv, serialization

I am trying to take an array of filenames and output the following...

```
a:1:{s:4:"docs";a:4:{i:0;a:1:{s:15:"property_imgurl";s:63:"http://wwww.example.com/image1.jpg";}i:1;a:1:{s:15:"property_imgurl";s:63:"http://wwww.example.com/image2.jpg";}i:2;a:1:{s:15:"property_imgurl";s:63:"http://wwww.example.com/image3.jpg";}i:3;a:1:{s:15:"property_imgurl";s:63:"http://wwww.example.com/image4.jpg";}}}
```

This is what I have so far...

```
<?php
$serialized_data = serialize(array('http://www.example.com/image1.jpg', 'http://www.example.com/image2.jpg', 'http://www.example.com/image3.jpg', 'http://www.example.com/image4.jpg'));
echo  $serialized_data . '<br>';
?>
```

But this is giving me...

```
a:4:{i:0;s:34:"http://www.example.com/image1.jpg";i:1;s:34:"http://www.example.com/image2.jpg";i:2;s:34:"http://www.example.com/image3.jpg";i:3;s:34:"http://www.example.com/image4.jpg";}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Unserialize the first serialized array and see what's its structure is. Then copy it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. You're just using numeric keys instead of strings like the supposed output you want. That's why the output is different.

Comment: Returns a string containing a byte-stream representation of value that can be stored anywhere.

Note that this is a binary string which may include null bytes, and needs to be stored and handled as such. For example, serialize() output should generally be stored in a BLOB field in a database, rather than a CHAR or TEXT field.  . What you are trying ? unserialise give corrct data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the serialized array. You're just not creating the array like you want it to be. PHP can't guess how you really want your array to be, so you have to tell PHP how you want it to be. So what you need to do is to change the input array correctly.

You're giving

```
array('http://www.example.com/image1.jpg', 'http://www.example.com/image2.jpg', 'http://www.example.com/image3.jpg', 'http://www.example.com/image4.jpg')
```

and that's completely different from the serialized array how it should be. Your Array needs to look like this

```
array('docs' => array(array('property_imgurl' => 'http://www.example.com/image1.jpg'), array('property_imgurl' => 'http://www.example.com/image2.jpg'), array('property_imgurl' => 'http://www.example.com/image3.jpg'), array('property_imgurl' => 'http://www.example.com/image4.jpg')))
```

[Look at this eval](http://3v4l.org/N3cLR)

Answer (score 2):

You're just missing the array key definitions.

```
$serialized = array(array('docs' => array(array('property_imgurl' => 'http://www.example.com/image4.jpg'))));
```

As you can see, each URL has a key of `property_imgurl` and each of those array is part of a parent array with a key of `docs`

[Here's the eval.in](https://eval.in/193816)